# Is it a legal requirement for a shop owner in India to give me a receipt if I purchased something in their shop?

Tags: india, legal, purchase, receipt

Is it a legal requirement for a shop owner in India to give me a receipt if I purchased something in their shop?

I'm asking as I purchased a SIM card in a shop of one of the main phone operators in India and they wouldn't give me a receipt for it, which surprised me.

Comment: I hate to link to Quora but this seems relevant: https://www.quora.com/Why-dont-some-shopkeepers-in-India-provide-a-bill-of-receipt-for-the-purchase-of-an-item

Comment: SIM cards are free

Comment: @Dheer not when they are prepaid.

Answer (score 1):

It is a legal requirement as per various shop acts.

Quite a few small shops don't give receipts to avoid taxes

Comment: Thanks, I'd be curious to know which  various shop acts. (also, showing the legal text  to the shop owner would help to get receipts)